# Akka Actor System not scaling up from 4 core to 16 core

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I made an actor system where I have a collector actor and a decoder actor. On my PC (4 processors), I am able to see the difference in the resource usage when I increase the number of files to decode but as soon I deploy it so server (16 cores), it uses only 20% of CPU. I am running the system with 4 decoders on PC and 16 decoders on server (1 collector in both cases). What could be the reason? Is there a way to allocate specific resources to actor system?

1. I have tried all the different dispatchers and executors.
2. I am not shutting any of the actors throughout the process.

Comment: Sounds like a classic case of being I/O bound vs being CPU bound.  My guess is that you are performing blocking I/O operations and that is the limiting factor that is not allowing you to reach full CPU potential

Comment: Thanks!!! Could you please have a look at my description in comments to the answer and suggest if I need to change something.